# Remove other panels on the same form

Tags: c#, winforms, panel

I have a form (C#) and several panels on it.
On one panel, I put a button which remove all panels on the form once it is clicked.
Here is my code:

```
        mainForm = (MainForm)this.FindForm();
        foreach (Control c in mainForm.Controls)
        {
            if (c is Panel)
            {
                mainForm.Controls.Remove(c);
                this.Refresh();
            }
        }
```

The problems is: It can't find any panel on mainForm.Controls
How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could do something like `panel1.Hide();`?

Comment: Thank you. I 've solved it. I find control by name and remove it.

Comment: This code doesn't properly remove panels either.  Never modify the collection you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

At least one problem with your code is you aren't allowed to update your list while you're in a foreach loop.  But you're modifying `mainForm.Controls` at the same loop where you're iterating through it.  Sometimes WinForms silently swallows these exceptions and you don't realize they even occurred.

So try creating your list of panels up front, and then see if it works.  (make sure you've got `using System.Linq;` at the top).

```
    var panels = mainForm.Controls.OfType<Panel>().ToArray();
    foreach (var panel in panels)
    {
        mainForm.Controls.Remove(panel);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using `foreach`, you have to loop through the `Controls` in a reverse direction, if using `for`, you have to loop through it from the last control to the first (reverse order):

```
foreach(Control c in mainForm.Controls.OfType<Control>().Reverse())
{
    if (c is Panel)
    {
      mainForm.Controls.Remove(c);      
    }
}
```

I think in this case, you should use a `for` instead to loop through the `Controls` from the last index to the first. This is the best solution of any other. `foreach` doesn't always replace the `for` and `LINQ` is not always the best. This approach doesn't require any other execution to select items from your collection, order your collection and memory to hold some additional variable or reference:

```
for(int i = mainForm.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--){
  if(mainForm.Controls[i] is Panel){
     mainForm.Controls.RemoveAt(i);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's *much* safer to use `ToArray` instead of `Reverse`.  `Reverse` is lazy-loaded so this code is still modifying the same collection it's iterating on.  It'll work in this limited case, but as soon as you want to add or swap elements, it bombs.  `ToArray` takes a snapshot that is then completely independent of the original collection, so you can remove, add, swap, whatever on the original collection from within the foreach and not worry.

Comment: @DaxFohl no bomb here, In fact `foreach(Control c in Controls)` is the same to `for(int i = 0; i < Controls.Count; i++)`, we don't modify anything here in this `foreach`, `c` is still references to a `Control` in the `Controls` collection and we just pass this `reference` into the `Remove(...)` method. For more optimized code, you can define an `IEnumerable<Control>` variable to hold `mainForm.Controls.OfType<Control>().Reverse()` before looping through that `IEnumerable<Control>` instead.